# inserting array of objects in db , only getting the last object data in console

Tags: javascript, node.js

here is my code, `function insert_data` receives an array of objects and loops through them and stores them  in database

```
function connect_to_mysql(callback){
    var con = mysql.createConnection(config.db);
    con.connect(function(err) {
        if (err){
            callback(true , null );
        } else {
            callback(false , con );
        }
    });
}


function insert_data(insert_data_stack){


    connect_to_mysql( function(err,conn) {
        if(!err)
        {
            for( var ikay in insert_data_stack )
            {
                 var query_data = insert_data_stack[ikay];
                console.log( ' inserting ---------------->' + ikay );
                console.log( query_data);

                    var query = conn.query('INSERT INTO transactions SET ?', query_data, function(err, result) {
                    if (err)
                    {
                        console.log(err.sqlMessage)                    }
                    else
                    {
                        console.log(' >>>> INSERTED >>>>> ' + query_data.trace_code );
                    }
                });
            }
          //  conn.end();
        }
    });

}
```

here is the problem , in this line `console.log(' >>>> INSERTED >>>>> ' + query_data.trace_code );` i only get the reace_Code of last object

here is my output

```
inserting ---------------->0
{ amount: '1000',
  payment_time: '‪20',
  full_cart: '6274121185233616',
  trace_code: '045330',
  account_id: 5,
  dig4_cart: '3616' }
 inserting ---------------->1
{ amount: '1000',
  payment_time: '‪20',
  full_cart: '6274121185233616',
  trace_code: '045138',
  account_id: 5,
  dig4_cart: '3616' }
 inserting ---------------->2
{ amount: '1000',
  payment_time: '‪20',
  full_cart: '6274121185233616',
  trace_code: '044868',
  account_id: 5,
  dig4_cart: '3616' }
 >>>> INSERTED >>>>> 044868
 >>>> INSERTED >>>>> 044868
 >>>> INSERTED >>>>> 044868
```

why do i only get the last object `trace_code` ?

Comment: try `result.trace_code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time that line of the code is executed, the for-loop has finished.

For explanation:https://dzone.com/articles/why-does-javascript-loop-only-use-last-value

Try changing your insert_data function to the following:

```
function insert_data(insert_data_stack)
{
    connect_to_mysql( function(err,conn) {
        if(!err)
        {
            for( var ikay in insert_data_stack )
            {
                var query_data = insert_data_stack[ikay];
                console.log( ' inserting ---------------->' + ikay );
                console.log( query_data);
                // see https://dzone.com/articles/why-does-javascript-loop-only-use-last-value
                let traceCode = query_data.trace_code;

                var query = conn.query('INSERT INTO transactions SET ?', query_data, function(err, result) {
                    if (err)
                    {
                        console.log(err.sqlMessage)                    
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        console.log(' >>>> INSERTED >>>>> ' + traceCode );
                    }
                });
            }
          //  conn.end();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanx , makes sense i should have known by the fact all the ` >>>> INSERTED >>>>> ` apear at the end